# Dependency version not resolved from ext block build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have added some dependency in my `build.gradle` file like this

```
ext {
  boxableVersion = '1.5.bq'
}
dependencies {
  implementation group: "com.github.dhorions", name:'boxable', version:${boxableVersion}
}
```

This was working seamlessly until I changed my JDK version from 1.8 to 11. Now, When I am trying to build the project, the following error shows up in my `build.gradle` file

> Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-bin.zip'.
>   Build file '/home/christine/christine/projectsFromGit/pdfcreator/build.gradle' line: 43
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'pdfcreator'.
>   Could not find method $() for arguments [build_4fl1snfk49qgbmumnf1gg989h$_run_closure3$_closure11@d7c9f2a] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

If i give version directly like this, the project is building successfully

```
implementation group: "com.github.dhorions", name:'boxable', version:'1.5.bq'
```

How can i give versions externally like I was doing before?

Answer (score 3):

The following syntax `version:${boxableVersion}` in your dependency declaration is not valid. It's not related to your JDK version, it's just that `${...}` means nothing in Gradle DSL or Groovy syntax.

If you want to define version in an 'ext' property, you can then reference this property directly with `version: boxableVersion` (ext properties are made available directly in the script through the "groovy magic"), or you can use Groovy [String interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) notation (please note the double-quote `"`)

```
 version: "${boxableVersion}"
```

Or , in a simpler way:

```
implementation "com.github.dhorions:boxable:${boxableVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
ext {
    boxableVersion = '1.5.bq'
}
dependencies {
    implementation group: "com.github.dhorions", name:'boxable', version:"${boxableVersion}"
}
```